# How to return an entire array from datalayer as an array in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-tag-manager

I have an array in the datalayer I would like to access as a variable in Google Tag Manager.  I want the entire array though, not just a value from a specific property...

I am trying to fire an eCommerce track like this:

```
<script>
analytics.track(‘Product List Viewed’, {
list_id: ‘Products List’,
products:
‘{{productListArray}}’
});
</script>
```

The {{productListArray}} variable, a custom javascript type GTM variable, I would like to return the full array from the datalayer variable called {{productList}}, which is a datalayer variable, with variable type of Array in the GTM debugger, that has this value:

```
[
{
product_id: ‘132699’,
sku: ‘Brand Name - 132699’,
brand: ‘Brand Name’,
name: ‘Product Name 1’,
price: 1.00,
position: 1,
category: ‘category2’,
},{
product_id: ‘132702’,
sku: ‘Brand Name - 132702’,
brand: ‘Brand Name’,
name: ‘Product Name 2’,
price: 1.00,
position: 2,
category: ‘category1’
}
]
```

I have been able to pull out a list of specific elements of the array, like product_id, using this method:

```
function() {
  var products = {{productList}};
  return products.map(function(prod) { return prod.product_id; });
```

...but I’d like to know the best approach for getting the entire array, with all objects in their entirety, so I can push the entire thing as a single variable in my Product List View track call.
I could probably store the array as text when pushed to the datalayer, but that seems like a bad workaround. How do I pull in the entire array of objects instead of just the values for a specific field?

---

UPDATE 12-4 - to add how the datalayer push looks like:

```css
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'productListViewed',
    'productList': [{
        'product_id': 132699,
        'sku': 'Brand Name - 132699',
        'brand': 'Brand Name',
        'name': 'Product Name 1',
        'price': 1.00,
        'position': 1,
        'category': 'category2'
    }, {
        'product_id': 132702,
        'sku': 'Brand Name - 132702',
        'brand': 'Brand Name',
        'name': 'Product Name 2',
        'price': 1.00,
        'position': 2,
        'category': 'category1'
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 07-12-2019**

I'm not answering this based on what works for analytics, I'm purely answering the core query, how to access the dataLayer array as a variable.

To access the array create a dataLayer variable "productList" in GTM.

[image: productList dataLayer variable]

In your tag, reference the dataLayer variable :

```
<script>
analytics.track('Product List Viewed', {
list_id: 'Products List',
products:
{{productList}}
});
</script>
```

You can create the stringified variable too if you wish:

```
<script>
analytics.track('Product List Viewed', {
list_id: 'Products List',
products:
JSON.stringify({{productList}})
});
</script>
```

**Original Answer**

Assuming that you are pushing the data:

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'productListViewed',
    'productData': {
        'productList': [{
            'product_id': 132699,
            'sku': 'Brand Name - 132699',
            'brand': 'Brand Name',
            'name': 'Product Name 1',
            'price': 1.00,
            'position': 1,
            'category': 'category2'
        }, {
            'product_id': 132702,
            'sku': 'Brand Name - 132702',
            'brand': 'Brand Name',
            'name': 'Product Name 2',
            'price': 1.00,
            'position': 2,
            'category': 'category1'
        }]
    }
})
```

You would access the array with a GTM dataLayer variable productData.productList: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7683362#data_layer
When I create a dataLayer variable I name it the same as the object reference:

Then in your analytics tag either add as a dimension or within GTM create the script:

```
<script>
analytics.track('Product List Viewed', {
list_id: 'Products List',
products:
{{productData.productList}}
});
</script>
```

You can create the stringified variable too if you wish:

```
<script>
analytics.track('Product List Viewed', {
list_id: 'Products List',
products:
JSON.stringify({{productData.productList}})
});
</script>
```

This may be useful reading: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/access-array-members-in-the-data-layer/

Comment: Thanks for the help here! The productData object isnt there for us - it's just event productListViewed and an object array under productList, at the same nest level as you have for 'productData'.  Are we required to nest objects like you have under productData or is there a way to read the unnested object array of productList if it were promoted to the same level as your productData object?

Comment: It might be best if you paste the data you are working with. I'm not clear on why you're using script tags for analytics instead of GTM either.

Comment: I just updated the question to show what my datalayer push looks like, so you can see that the products list is not nested under productData.  This seems to be the issue - where I can't access this unless it is nested.  How do i access the full array of productList as I have it being pushed, instead of when it is nested like you had t under productData?

Comment: Added an edit, please accept as a solution if it answers the question suitably.

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't work, which is what brought me here to begin with.  It only works when I have it under an outer object.  Any ideas as to why?  Have you tested to see if it works for you?

Comment: Working fine for me. I've created the tag that fires on event "productListViewed":

<script>
  (function(){
   console.log(typeof {{productList}});
   console.log(JSON.stringify({{productList}}));
  })();
</script>

It outputs:

object

[{"product_id":132699,"sku":"Brand Name - 132699","brand":"Brand Name","name":"Product Name 1","price":1,"position":1,"category":"category2"},{"product_id":132702,"sku":"Brand Name - 132702","brand":"Brand Name","name":"Product Name 2","price":1,"position":2,"category":"category1"}]